# UITableView with searcher and selecting the UITableViewcell both in initial loading of cell and after search of tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search, checkmark

I am having a tableview that's used for both the search result and whole list. I am using a imageView in the tableviewcell that will change to tick mark when clicked. I have completed click function and search filter everything but I could not show the tick mark after the user click the tableviewcell in search result and I need to populate that tick mark in the whole list of tick mark. 
I have attached the code for your reference.

This is my cell function

```
class playlistcelllaist : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var img_Show: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_Title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_SubTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var img_play: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var image_tick: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellselectionButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var trackidtext: UILabel!


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        if selected {

        }
    }


    @IBAction func cellselectionButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if constantsList.playTypeArray.filtereArray.count == 0 {
            //check
            if  image_tick.image == UIImage(named:"round_done-1")  {
                constantsList.playTypeArray.boolArrayAddplaylist[sender.tag] = false
                let dataToberemoved = ((constantsList.playTypeArray.arr_subCatagriesLecture.object(at: sender.tag)as AnyObject).value(forKey: "track_id")!)
                constantsList.playTypeArray.dataArrayInPlaylist.removeObject(identicalTo: dataToberemoved)
                print(constantsList.playTypeArray.dataArrayInPlaylist)
                image_tick.image = UIImage(named:"round")


                //uncheck
            }else if image_tick.image == UIImage(named:"round") {
                constantsList.playTypeArray.boolArrayAddplaylist[sender.tag] = true
                constantsList.playTypeArray.dataArrayInPlaylist.add((((constantsList.playTypeArray.arr_subCatagriesLecture.object(at: sender.tag)as AnyObject).value(forKey: "track_id")))!)
                print(constantsList.playTypeArray.dataArrayInPlaylist)
                image_tick.image = UIImage(named:"round_done-1")
            }


            if constantsList.playTypeArray.dataArrayInPlaylist.count == 0 {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "navigationBarnameChange"), object: nil)
            }else {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "navigationBarnameChange"), object: nil)
            }
        }else {

            print(sender.tag)
            //check
            if  image_tick.image == UIImage(named:"round_done-1")  {
                let datainfilteredArray = constantsList.playTypeArray.filtereArray[sender.tag]
                    constantsList.playTypeArray.dataArrayInPlaylist.removeObject(identicalTo: datainfilteredArray.track_id)

                print(constantsList.playTypeArray.dataArrayInPlaylist)
                image_tick.image = UIImage(named:"round")

                //uncheck
            }else if image_tick.image == UIImage(named:"round") {
               let datainfilteredArray11 = constantsList.playTypeArray.filtereArray[sender.tag]
                constantsList.playTypeArray.dataArrayInPlaylist.add(datainfilteredArray11.track_id)
                print(constantsList.playTypeArray.dataArrayInPlaylist)
                image_tick.image = UIImage(named:"round_done-1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchBool == false {
            return searchResults.count
        }else {
            return constantsList.playTypeArray.filtereArray.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let table_cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "playlistaddition", for: indexPath) as! playlistcelllaist                            

        // Filtered Array

        if searchBool == true {
            let trackDataFilter = constantsList.playTypeArray.filtereArray[indexPath.row]
            //classname
            let x : Int = trackDataFilter.classname
            let className = String(x)
            //Play Image
            table_cell.img_play.image=#imageLiteral(resourceName: "play_track")
            //title
            table_cell.lbl_Title.text = trackDataFilter.title
            //Subtitle
            table_cell.lbl_SubTitle.text = String(format: "Class - %@ | %@",  className,(trackDataFilter.time))
            //Color
            table_cell.lbl_SubTitle.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
            //Setting trackId to hidden label
            table_cell.trackidtext.text = "\(trackDataFilter.track_id)"
            //image

           // constantsList.playTypeArray.imageLecture = trackDataFilter.imageUrl
            table_cell.img_Show.sd_setImage(with: trackDataFilter.imageUrl )

            table_cell.selectionStyle = .none
                    if  constantsList.playTypeArray.dataArrayInPlaylist.count != 0 {
                        for travkID in  constantsList.playTypeArray.dataArrayInPlaylist {
                            print(travkID)
                            if travkID as! Int ==  trackDataFilter.track_id {
                                  table_cell.image_tick.image = UIImage(named:"round_done-1")
                            }else {
                                table_cell.image_tick.image = UIImage(named:"round")
                            }
                        }
                    }else {
            table_cell.image_tick.image = UIImage(named:"round")
        }
            return table_cell
        }

        let trackdata = searchResults[indexPath.row]
        constantsList.playTypeArray.boolArrayAddplaylist.append(false)
        let x : Int = trackdata.classNumber as! Int
        let className = String(x)
        table_cell.img_play.image=#imageLiteral(resourceName: "play_track")
        table_cell.lbl_Title.text = trackdata.songTitle
        table_cell.lbl_SubTitle.text = String(format: "Class - %@ | %@",  className,(trackdata.timeoftrack!))
        table_cell.lbl_SubTitle.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        table_cell.trackidtext.text = "\(((constantsList.playTypeArray.arr_subCatagriesLecture.object(at: indexPath.row)as AnyObject).value(forKey: "track_id")as! Int))"
        table_cell.cellselectionButton.tag = indexPath.row

        constantsList.playTypeArray.imageLecture = ((constantsList.playTypeArray.arr_subCatagriesLecture.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "image_url") as! String)
        table_cell.img_Show.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: ((constantsList.playTypeArray.arr_subCatagriesLecture.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "image_url") as! String)), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))

//        if(constantsList.playTypeArray.boolArrayAddplaylist[indexPath.row]) {
//            //  table_cell.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411765, green: 0.7294117647, blue: 0.4549019608, alpha: 1)
//            //  table_cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
//            table_cell.image_tick.image = UIImage(named:"round_done-1")
//        } else {
//            //  table_cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
//            table_cell.image_tick.image = UIImage(named:"round")
//        }

        if  constantsList.playTypeArray.dataArrayInPlaylist.count != 0 {
            for travkID in  constantsList.playTypeArray.dataArrayInPlaylist {
                print(travkID)
                if travkID as! Int ==  (constantsList.playTypeArray.arr_subCatagriesLecture.object(at: indexPath.row)as AnyObject).value(forKey: "track_id")as! Int {
                    table_cell.image_tick.image = UIImage(named:"round_done-1")
                }else {
                    table_cell.image_tick.image = UIImage(named:"round")
                }
            }
        }else {
            table_cell.image_tick.image = UIImage(named:"round")
        }

        table_cell.selectionStyle = .none

        return table_cell
    }

    func collectionSkeletonView(_ skeletonView: UITableView, cellIdentifierForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> ReusableCellIdentifier {
        return "playlistaddition"
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        view.endEditing(true)
        if cell.isSkeletonActive {
            cell.hideSkeleton()
        }
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: CELL_HEIGHT)
        cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
        cell.alpha = 0

        UIView.beginAnimations("rotation", context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        cell.alpha = 1
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//        if searchBool == true {
//            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! playlistcelllaist
//            let labelContent = cell.trackidtext.text
//            print(labelContent!)
//            constantsList.playTypeArray.track_idString = labelContent
//        }else {
//            print("Normal")
//        }
    }
```

While searching and selecting the UITableViewCell the tick mark should be also shown in the whole list of tableview without selecting. Try to give me a solution with my code or else just give your logic with your own example

Comment: I have given the cell selection to none, so only I have return the condition in button in cell .

Comment: It would be nice, if you could prepare your pasted code a bit, where all the unrelevant parts are not included, like prints, out commented code and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you meant, it looks like you are writing some complicated code to do a simple thing, but in a normal scenario, you just have to keep an array of the selected items (some kinda id - sender tag / indexPath.row cannot be used, coz it changes with the number of rows)use primary key of each item. Just use `Alastar`'s answer below and try keeping a list of selected items. Then set the tick from `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method. Don't write any selection code in the cell. just the button click and get out through delegate.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use delegation to solve this.

setup a a protocol and delegation in your cell.

```
protocol CellDelegate: class {
   func buttonPressed(sender: MyTableViewCell)
}

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: CellDelegate?

    @objc func cellselectionButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.buttonPressed(sender: self)
    }
}
```

then in your `cellForRowAt` set:

```
table_cell.delegate = self
```

and so make your viewController conform to your protocol and the job is done

```
extension YourViewController: CellDelegate {
    func buttonPressed(sender: MyTableViewCell) {
       // do all your stuff here with the sender...
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not the solution I wanted